# Error for Angular5

Tags: angular5

Install the  ng2-select-ex via npm package manager

`npm i ng2-select-ex --save`

Using this repo - https://optimistex.github.io/ng2-select-ex/ results following error: No provider for DomSanitizer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)?